# How to read or capture trace messages in runtime and store them in a string with C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, trace

I'm working on a Machine Learning project with C#/Windows Forms which makes use of a library called *SharpLearning*. This library has been considered in the application since it is very straightfoward to build, train and test models. However, I have been struggling to find a way to capture or read, in real-time, the trace messages emitted during the training process of a given model in order to get its current epoch number. This information, when captured and properly stored in a string, will help to update a progress bar (`currentEpoch / numEpochs`). The main code snippet concerning the current epoch information, which can be found on the SharpLearning's Github repository (https://github.com/mdabros/SharpLearning/blob/master/src/SharpLearning.Neural/Learners/NeuralNetLearner.cs), is the following:

```
for (int iteration = 0; iteration < m_iterations; iteration++)
{
      // ...
      Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Iteration: {0:000} - Loss {1:0.00000} - Validation: {2:0.00000} - Time (ms): {3}",
                    (iteration + 1), currentLoss, validationLoss, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds));

      // ...   
}
```

I have already tried reading in runtime a log file which was written concurrently by a trace listener called `TextWriterTraceListener`. But, due to the multithreading environment, I was not able to make this reading in real-time. Is there a easier way to capture or read the information of each trace message and, preferably, store them instantly in a string, without the need of log files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at existing Logging mechanisms like Log4Net ?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Log4Net only manages to write log texts into files or console outputs.I've found nothing similar in Log4Net for reading trace messages. I have looked for other resources, but without success. What I need is somekind of method which reads these trace messages in real-time as they show in output window. If there is some way to use Log4Net, for example, for reading these trace messages, please let me know.

Comment: Create a custom [TraceListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracelistener?view=netframework-4.8) and override the `WriteLine` method to raise an event that you can subscribe to.  Then add an instance of that class to `Trace.Listeners`.  `Trace.WriteLine` should write to all listeners in `Trace.Listeners`.